# Kivy: Different Outcome on Android and Mac

Tags: android, macos, kivy

Can anyone explain to me why the same code would look completely different on 2 different OS'?

It doesn't seem to be a dpi thing.

I've been struggling already with the gui side of things as I've never done any front end but this really isn't helping.

[Mac Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geGcf.jpg)

[Android Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1xjN.jpg)

```
<SetupScreen>:
name: "setupscreen"
orientation: 'vertical'
ScrollView:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        padding: dp(48)
        spacing: 25
        MDLabel:
            font_style: 'Title'
            theme_text_color: 'Primary'
            text: "Setup"
            halign: "center"
        Divider:
        MDLabel:
            font_style: 'Subhead'
            theme_text_color: 'Primary'
            text: "User & Allocation"
            halign: "center"
        MDTextField:
            id: username_input
            hint_text: "Name"
            helper_text: "Please enter your name here."
            required: True
            write_tab: False
            on_text_validate: annual_input.focus=True;
        MDTextField:
            id: annual_input
            hint_text: "Annual Leave Alowance"
            helper_text: "Enter the number of annual leave days you get (ie 30)"
            required: True
            write_tab: False
            on_text_validate: sick_input.focus=True;
        MDTextField:
            id: sick_input
            hint_text: "Sick Leave Alowance"
            helper_text: "Enter the number of sick leave days you get (ie 30)"
            required: True
            write_tab: False
            on_text_validate: special_input.focus=True;
        MDTextField:
            id: special_input
            hint_text: "Special Leave Alowance"
            helper_text: "Enter the number of special leave days you get (ie 30)"
            required: True
            write_tab: False
            on_text_validate: setup_confirm_button.focus=True;
        MDLabel:
            font_style: 'Subhead'
            theme_text_color: 'Primary'
            text: "Select Non Workdays"
            halign: "center"
        LabeledCheckBox:
            id: mon_chkbox
            label_text: "Monday"
        LabeledCheckBox:
            id: tue_chkbox
            label_text: "Tuesday"
        LabeledCheckBox:
            id: wed_chkbox
            label_text: "Wednesday"
        LabeledCheckBox:
            id: thu_chkbox
            label_text: "Thursday"
        LabeledCheckBox:
            id: fri_chkbox
            label_text: "Friday"
        LabeledCheckBox:
            id: sat_chkbox
            label_text: "Saturday"
        LabeledCheckBox:
            id: sun_chkbox
            label_text: "Sunday"
        MDRaisedButton:
            id: setup_confirm_button
            text: "Confirm"
            halign: "center"
            opposite_colors: True
            on_release: root.on_confirm(username_input.text, annual_input.text, sick_input.text, special_input.text)

<LabeledCheckBox>:
    cols: 2
    spacing: 50
    MDLabel:
        font_style: 'Body1'
        theme_text_color: 'Primary'
        text: root.label_text
        halign: "center"
    MDCheckbox:
        halign: "left"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.